# How to fail a conda package build when there are errors on run_test.py

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am creating a conda recipe, and have added run_test.py . These are unittest classes. 
Unfortunatly, when there are errors, the package is still created.

My question, how to inform conda that the test failed, and it should not continue with the package build.

run_test.py contains :

> suit = unittest.TestLoader().discover("../tests/unitTest")#, pattern="test[AP][la]*[sr].py")
>   unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suit )

I do add the files in meta.yaml

> test:
>    files:
>      - ../tests/unittest/

This is the output:

> Ran 16 tests in 2.550s
>
> FAILED (errors=5)
>
> ===== PACKAGE-NAME-None-np18py27_0 OK ====

I want to stop the build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script needs to exit nonzero. If the tests fail, call `sys.exit(1)` in the script.

Answer (score 2):

In `run_test.py`, you can invoke `unittest.main()` by doing the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The conda build process will automatically fail if the tests do not succeed. This link will help demonstrate: [invoking unittest main method](https://pymotw.com/2/unittest/)

Comment: **This is the canonical answer.** Sadly, as always, the accepted answer is substantially more ambiguous and hence less practically useful. *This is why we can't have nice StackOverflow things.*